# Yii 1.1 create custom user friendly URLs

Tags: php, yii, url-rewriting, url-routing, parameters

I am trying to workout a custom URL requirement. We are a product based website, and url to each product is like

```
https://www.domainname.com/product/index/id/product_id
```

Now i want the urls to be user friendly and something like this..

```
https://www.domainname.com/productcustomurl
```

To achieve this i have created a field named `custom_url` in the table `product` where the customurl will be stored by product creator during the product creation. For this i have created a rule in the params.php like this:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
'<id:(.*?)>' => 'product/index' //this rule
```

assuming this will redirect user whenever anyone hits `https://www.domainname.com/productcustomurl` with `productcustomurl` in parameter `id`, which is working fine, but the problem is this is redirecting each and everything to the `product/index` overriding all the other routes like `site/index` or `site/about` etc etc, which is an issue. I want them to be working. How do i achieve it, without affecting the normal routes of the website??
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your last line of config with this:

```
'<productcustomurl:\w>' => 'product/index'
```

Now,  `actionIndex` of `ProductController`, should be like this:

```
public function actionIndex($productcustomurl)
{
     //Now, you can find a product by its custom url, and pass the finded product object to the view
}
```